# Looking for identification of an item

Tags: identification

I have had some trouble identifying this piece of hardware, even with the help of the inter webs. I have disassembled the printer (Brother HL-2270W or a similar device), so getting it to run is a bit of an issue for me too, so. My questions is: what is this device? It obviously looks like it is a motor or servo or etc of some sort, but specific name would help. Then my next question would be this: can I somehow reuse it with, say, an Arduino Uno r3?

Note: I am new to this sort of thing, and so would not be surprised if something i ask is misrepresented in some way or vague. Thanks in advance for understanding.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where in the printer was it taken from? This will help identify the part easier.

Comment: It was taken from a side, connected to a rather large gear(compared to the rest), and that was connected to several other gears.. Specifically what part of the printer, I am unsure.. I'll see if i can find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a **3-Phase Brushless DC Motor**.  The `U`,`V`,`W` markings are apparently standard notation.  The three little chips labeled `HU`,`HV`,`HW` are likely **Hall Effect Sensors** (or simply **Hall Sensors**) for position/speed feedback.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a ton, considering I'd never know that otherwise.